# How can I make my slack app ignore messages in group channels?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I created a slack app bot which can communicate with users, and it has been integrated with a group channel. Now the bot will respond to users when they input sth in the group channel, but I want it to ignore the messages in the group channel and only reply direct messages. Is it possible to do this?

The scope added to the bot:

```
  - users:read
  - users:read.email
  - chat:write
  - app_mentions:read
  - channels:history
  - commands
  - files:read
  - files:write
  - groups:history
  - im:history
  - incoming-webhook
  - mpim:history
  - remote_files:read
  - remote_files:share
  - remote_files:write
  - calls:read
```

Comment: I assume you have subscribed to some events, as your app reacts to those messages. Can you try unsubscribing events related to group/channels ?

Comment: Hi @SuyashGaur Thanks for your suggestion! I'll try it.